# Add one or two files to be parsed by PHP in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'd like to change one text file on my server to be parsed by PHP - how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you already have the appropriate lines in Apache to enable PHP in general. To use PHP to parse a non .php ending file, you can use a ForceType directive in either an htaccess file or in the apache config. For example:

```
<Files ~ '^(file1.txt|anotherfile.txt)$'>
        ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

That expression is flexible and you can add additional files to match within the parentheses using another pipe character.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot: ended up using <FilesMatch "^filename.extension$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php</FilesMatch> - any idea which one is better?

Comment: They're both equivalent. FilesMatch is a newer* directive that makes it really obvious that you're doing a match. The ~ syntax goes back to when I started using Apache (1.2 maybe). Regarding the difference between SetHandler and ForceType, they're also basically equivalent. ForceType sets the content-type, after which Apache will use the default handler for that content type. SetHandler explicitly tells Apache to use that particular handler for the file.